# JavaFX: How do I move a button above other nodes of the same z-property during animation with TranslateTransition?

Tags: animation, javafx

I have a StackPane that contains a button that I want to move to another Stackpane. In the middle of the path there is another Pane that also contains a button. When i transition the movable button it always "hovers" under the button in the middle.

```
public class HelloController {

    @FXML
    private StackPane startPane;
    @FXML
    private StackPane endPane;
    @FXML private Button button;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), button);
        transition.setFromX(startPane.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() - endPane.getBoundsInParent().getMinX());
        transition.setFromY(startPane.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - endPane.getBoundsInParent().getMinY());
        transition.setToX(0);
        transition.setToY(0);

        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            ((StackPane) button.getParent()).getChildren().remove(button);

            // Move the button to the target pane with animation
            endPane.getChildren().add(button);

            // Bring the button to the front
            button.toFront();

            transition.play();
        });
    }
}
```

**Here you can see the node hierarchy of the Scene**
[Node hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT9kA.png)

Here is the FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<AnchorPane prefHeight="251.0" prefWidth="379.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo1.HelloController">
   <children>
      <StackPane fx:id="startPane" prefHeight="119.0" prefWidth="123.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="button" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick" text="Hello!" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <StackPane fx:id="endPane" layoutX="242.0" layoutY="119.0" prefHeight="119.0" prefWidth="123.0" style="-fx-background-color: yellow;" />
      <Pane fx:id="endPane1" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="66.0" prefHeight="119.0" prefWidth="123.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="123.0" prefWidth="126.0" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**How do i make it that the button is visible during the entire animation?**

I already tried setting the translateZ values of the starting pane and button to 10 and invoking the toFront() method for the button but nothing works.

Comment: good point, thanks

Comment: You need to move the pane containing the button to the front: `endPane.toFront()`.  Alternatively, flatten the layout strategy so all the components are in a single container.

Comment: Off-topic: why are you registering a button handler inside an existing button handler? Are you really intending that the button should be pressed twice to initiate the action?

Comment: Thank you so much! "endPane.toFront()" was the solution. About your question: i just isolated this snippet from my bigger project (chess application) an pasted it to the IntelliJ javafx sample project without giving it much thought :D but this way i could try to  solve the animation issue faster. Now it works for both so thanks again